# How can I build and run Doom 3 from source in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to build and run Doom 3 from the open source release in order to better understand how the engine works. Unfortunately I am not able to run the game from the binary I built. I just get the console, but cannot run the actual game.

Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded the source code from the game repo
2. Downloaded and installed the DirectX SDK
3. Purchased, downloaded and installed Doom 3 from Steam
4. Open the solution in the new folder using VS2010 SP1
5. Built the project
6. Ran it

The doom solution by default on the debug settings sets the command line to refer to the default steam doom3 installation path. This is the default command line arguments used to run the project from vstudio.

+set fs_basepath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3" +set com_allowConsole 1 +set si_pure 0

Doing that resulted in the console opening with the following log:

```
DOOM 1.3.1.1304 win-x86 Jan 23 2012 00:50:27
1596 MHz Intel CPU with MMX & SSE & SSE2 & SSE3 & HTT
8176 MB System Memory
0 MB Video Memory
Winsock Initialized
Found interface: {A3B0D223-3776-4D39-B7AD-9053DDB2E8D5} Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet - 0.0.0.0 NULL netmask - skipped
Found interface: {8FBA30BE-8F70-40B5-8C79-C32E8E1E74B8} Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) - 0.0.0.0 NULL netmask - skipped
Found interface: {80300E42-A240-45A3-97C5-261C0ED3B93B} Intel(R) WiFi Link 5300 AGN - 192.168.1.111/255.255.255.0
Sys_InitNetworking: adding loopback interface
doom using MMX & SSE & SSE2 & SSE3 for SIMD processing
enabled Flush-To-Zero mode
enabled Denormals-Are-Zero mode
------ Initializing File System ------
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\game00.pk4 with checksum 0x29cdb978
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\game01.pk4 with checksum 0x51c6981f
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\game02.pk4 with checksum 0xf3ec6f7
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\game03.pk4 with checksum 0x5d4230ea
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak000.pk4 with checksum 0x28d208f1
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak001.pk4 with checksum 0x40244be0
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak002.pk4 with checksum 0xc51ecdcd
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak003.pk4 with checksum 0xcd79d028
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak004.pk4 with checksum 0x765e4f8b
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak005.pk4 with checksum 0x8ffc3621
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak006.pk4 with checksum 0x95b65ab
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak007.pk4 with checksum 0x666bdb3c
Loaded pk4 C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak008.pk4 with checksum 0x23ae5993
Current search path:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3/base
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak008.pk4 (3 files)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak007.pk4 (38 files)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak006.pk4 (48 files)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak005.pk4 (63 files)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak004.pk4 (5137 files)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak003.pk4 (4676 files)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak002.pk4 (6120 files)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak001.pk4 (8972 files)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\pak000.pk4 (2698 files)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\game03.pk4 (2 files)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\game02.pk4 (2 files)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\game01.pk4 (2 files)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\doom 3\base\game00.pk4 (2 files)
game DLL: 0x0 in pak: 0x0
Addon pk4s:
file system initialized.
--------------------------------------
----- Initializing Decls -----
------------------------------
------- Initializing renderSystem --------
using ARB renderSystem
renderSystem initialized.
--------------------------------------
5206 strings read from strings/english.lang
Couldn't open journal files
execing editor.cfg
execing default.cfg
execing DoomConfig.cfg
couldn't exec autoexec.cfg
5206 strings read from strings/english.lang
----- Initializing Sound System ------
sound system initialized.
--------------------------------------
game using MMX & SSE & SSE2 & SSE3 for SIMD processing
enabled Flush-To-Zero mode
enabled Denormals-Are-Zero mode
--------- Initializing Game ----------
gamename: baseDOOM-1
gamedate: Jan 23 2012
Initializing event system
...473 event definitions
Initializing class hierarchy
...142 classes, 191092 bytes for event callbacks
Initializing scripts
Compiled 'weapon_pistol::Raise': 3091.7 ms
---------- Compile stats ----------

Memory usage:
     Strings: 79, 9648 bytes
  Statements: 67875, 1357500 bytes
   Functions: 2109, 250532 bytes
   Variables: 147376 bytes
    Mem used: 2476344 bytes
 Static data: 2277552 bytes
   Allocated: 3281600 bytes
 Thread size: 7068 bytes

...6 aas types
game initialized.
--------------------------------------
-------- Initializing Session --------
WARNING: idChoiceWindow::InitVars: gui 'guis/mainmenu.gui' window 'SNDBPrimary' references undefined cvar 's_driver'
session initialized
--------------------------------------
--- Common Initialization Complete ---
------------- Warnings ---------------
during DOOM 3 initialization...
WARNING: idChoiceWindow::InitVars: gui 'guis/mainmenu.gui' window 'SNDBPrimary' references undefined cvar 's_driver'
1 warnings

Type 'help' for dedicated server info.
```

I don't know if the warning I am getting is the problem or if there is something else.
Also, this is when the configuration being used is "Dedicated release", but I have also tried with "Dedicated Debug". It is my understanding that the "dedicated" versions don't use OpenAL but is there any other difference?

My main question is: How to just get this to run from source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Dedicated" in the configuration name refers to the game's dedicated multiplayer server. It's for sever operators exclusively, and runs an empty multiplayer server that exists solely to receive connections from other clients.

You don't want that. Run a configuration that starts with "Debug" or "Release" instead of "Dedicated."

Comment: Yeap. That was it. There was a compile time error when not using dedicated, but it was just a printf on the amount of audio memory. Just commented out and now its working perfectly. Thanks